# Laravel: How to deal with ResetPassword::createUrlUsing set in different packages' app provider?

Tags: laravel

In my **Laravel** API, I have two packages `my-packages/foo` and `my-packages/bar`. Each one is related to a SPA frontend (`foo.com` and `bar.com`) and has its own authentication guard (`api:foo` and `api:bar`) and users provider (`users:foo` and `users:bar`).

Users are logging in from SPA through **Laravel Passport** *Password Grant Token*.

To set up password recovery for each SPA, I've add this to the `boot()` method of `FooServiceProvider.php`:

```
ResetPassword::createUrlUsing(function ($notifiable, $token) {
    return config('foo.reset_password_url') .  $token;
});
```

And again in `BarServiceProvider.php`:

```
ResetPassword::createUrlUsing(function ($notifiable, $token) {
    return config('bar.reset_password_url') .  $token;
});
```

Now when I'm calling either of the two routes (`foo/forgot-password` or `bar/forgot-password`), the send reset link method is always sending the recover address of `foo`:

```
Route::post('foo/forgot-password', function (Request $request) {
  $request->validate(['email' => 'required|email']);
  Password::sendResetLink(
    $request->only('email')
  );
);
```

How should I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix by moving `ResetPassword::createUrlUsing` to the main `AppServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot()
{
    ResetPassword::createUrlUsing(function ($notifiable, $token) {
        $link = match (request()->path()) {
            'foo/forgot-password' => config('foo.reset_password_url') . $token,
            'bar/forgot-password' => config('bar.reset_password_url') . $token,
            default => null
        };
        return $link;
    });
}
```

It's not very elegant though, I'd prefer each package to manage its own password reset process.

#### EDIT

This could even be simplified this way:

```
public function boot()
{
    ResetPassword::createUrlUsing(function ($notifiable, $token) {
        return config(request()->segment(1) . '.reset_password_url') . $token;
    });
}
```